# How to put text from a document into a database?

Tags: php, database, mysql-workbench

I have a database set up and I have all my text in a word document. I know how to put all the text into the database, but my problem is that it doesn't output it exactly the way I have it like in the word document. When I echo is on a page it just shows the text like a regular text. an example of what I have in the document:

```
     This is the title.
             1.some text
             2.some text
```

this is what I'd get when I echo the data on a page:

```
     This is the title.1.some text2.some text
```

I am using mysql workbench. I am copy pasting from a microsoft word document into the database.

Comment: When you say "word document", do you mean a .doc file, or a regular .txt file?

Comment: Clear that it is a txt file

Comment: oh sorry I'll edit it with more information. I am copy pasting from a microsoft word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you copy from word you need to format all the text you want for example to show up as bold between "< strong> < /strong>" tags returns will be  etc. look up the right format.
Then once done you can paste it into your database. I presumed you were displaying it in some browser. Good luck